# getting client IP address in a webserver

Tags: delphi, server, ip, client, webserver

I developed a simple webserver in Delphi. It is a stand-alone type. How can I get the client IP address when a client connects to the server?

I saw this line in the unit:
FServer: TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge;

how can I get the IP of a client which connects to the webserver?

Answer (score 1):

`TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge` is not a standalone web server (`TIdHTTPServer` is), it is used to connect Indy as the backend for Embarcadero's [WebBroker](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Creating_WebBroker_Applications) tech.  In which case, if you are actually using WebBroker for your server then the client IP is available in the [`TWebRequest.RemoteAddr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Web.HTTPApp.TWebRequest.RemoteAddr) property.

Answer (score 1):

In a SOAP Server application, I've made something like this:

```
TwbServer = class(TInvokableClass, IwbServer)
  public
    function GetRemoteIP () : String; stdcall;
 end;

 function TwbServer.GetRemoteIP () : String; 
    var
       WebDispatcher: IWebDispatcherAccess;
    begin
       Supports(GetSOAPWebModule, IWebDispatcherAccess, WebDispatcher);
       Result :=  WebDispatcher.Request.RemoteIP;
    end;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).